# In Controller, return records with [verified_date] older than 3 months from current date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, date

I'm working on a Verify Assets view in my MVC5 Code-First webapp, and I am trying to (by default) return only those records in `INV_Assets` which have a `[verified_date]` older than 3 months back from the current `Date`.

I attempted the following, but receive

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression

for an error when loading the View:

```
public class VerifyAssetsController : Controller
{
    private InventoryTrackerContext db = new InventoryTrackerContext();

    // GET: VerifyAssets
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var iNV_Assets = db.INV_Assets.Where(i => i.verified_date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)).Include(i => i.Location).Include(i => i.Manufacturer).Include(i => i.Model).Include(i => i.Status).Include(i => i.Type).Include(i => i.Vendor);
        return View(await iNV_Assets.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Can anyone offer some insight into how to go about this?

Ideally I am wanting the default to be 3 months back from current date, and to then have `DropDowns` on the View which will allow the users to specify 1-12 `Months`/`Weeks`/`Days` back from the current `Date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calculating previous month inside the query, Get that value before the query and pass it like:

```
var previousDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
var iNV_Assets = db.INV_Assets
                   .Where(i => i.verified_date < previousDate)
                   .Include(i => i.Location)
                   .Include(i => i.Manufacturer)
                   .Include(i => i.Model)
                   .Include(i => i.Status)
                   .Include(i => i.Type)
                   .Include(i => i.Vendor);
```

*(I am not sure why you are adding all the `Include` statements, you may get rid of them if you are only going to select `Assets`)*

The reason your code is failing is it is trying to convert `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)` to under lying data source language *(probably SQL)* and it is failing in doing so.

Comment: Thanks Habib, that did the trick perfectly! On the Include, each of those are Maintenance tables I have set up as `ForeignKeys` on my `INV_Assets` Model -- Ex: `[Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]`.